# Extract a predictors form constparty object (CHAID output) in R

Tags: r, tree, party

I have a large dataset (questionnaire results) of mostly categorical variables. I have tested for dependency between the variables using chi-square test. There are incomprehensible number of dependencies between variables. I used the `chaid()` function in the CHAID package to detect interactions and separate out (what I hope to be) the underlying structure of these dependencies for each variable. What typically happens is that the chi-square test will reveal a large number of dependencies (say 10-20) for a variable and the `chaid` function will reduce this to something much more comprehensible (say 3-5). What I want to do is to extract the names of those variable that were shown to be relevant in the `chaid()` results.

The `chaid()` output is in the form of a `constparty` object. My question is how to extract the variable names associated with the nodes in such an object.

Here is a self contained code example:

```
library(evtree) # for the ContraceptiveChoice dataset
library(CHAID)
library(vcd)
library(MASS)

data("ContraceptiveChoice")
longform = formula(contraceptive_method_used ~ wifes_education + 
                 husbands_education +  wifes_religion + wife_now_working + 
                 husbands_occupation + standard_of_living_index + media_exposure)
z = chaid(longform, data = ContraceptiveChoice)
# plot(z)
z
# This is the part I want to do programatically
shortform = formula(contraceptive_method_used ~ wifes_education + husbands_occupation)
# The thing I want is a programatic way to extract 'shortform'  from 'z' 

# Examples of use of 'shortfom'   
loglm(shortform, data = ContraceptiveChoice)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible sollution:

```
nn <- nodeapply(z)
n.names= names(unlist(nn[[1]]))
ext <- unlist(sapply(n.names, function(x) grep("split.varid.", x, value=T)))
ext <- gsub("kids.split.varid.", "", ext)
ext <- gsub("split.varid.", "", ext)
dep.var <- as.character(terms(z)[1][[2]]) # get the dependent variable
plus = paste(ext, collapse=" + ")     
mul = paste(ext, collapse=" * ")
shortform <- as.formula(paste (dep.var, plus, sep = " ~ "))
satform <- as.formula(paste (dep.var, mul, sep = " ~ "))
mosaic(shortform, data = ContraceptiveChoice)
#stp <- step(glm(satform, data=ContraceptiveChoice, family=binomial), direction="both")
```